# Не все bitmap отрисовываются на экране. Android. Java

Tags: java, android, ооп, разработка-игр

Пишу игру  и почему-то не все bitmap отрисовываются
Метод draw в наследнике от View:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    timer.draw(canvas);
    background.draw(canvas);
    buttons.draw(canvas);
    board.draw(canvas); // Проблемный класс



    Paint mPaint = new Paint(); 
    mPaint.setTextSize(30);

    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    canvas.drawText(score + "/" + symbols, (float) (displaymetrics.widthPixels * 0.05), (float) (displaymetrics.heightPixels * 0.1), mPaint);


}
```

Метод draw в проблемном классе:

```
@Override
public  void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.draw(canvas);

    firstSymbol.draw(canvas);// Sprite
    secondSymbol.draw(canvas);// Sprite
    thirdSymbol.draw(canvas);// Sprite
    fourthSymbol.draw(canvas);// Sprite

    minusFourthSymbol.draw(canvas);// Sprite
    minusThirdSymbol.draw(canvas);// Sprite
    minusSecondSymbol.draw(canvas);// Sprite
    minusFirstSymbol.draw(canvas);// Sprite

}
```

Метод draw в родителе проблемного класса:

```
void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    board.draw(canvas);// Sprite
    symbol.draw(canvas);// Sprite
}
```

Метод draw в классе Sprite:

```
public void draw (Canvas canvas) {

    Paint p = new Paint();

    Rect destination = new Rect((int)x, (int)y, (int)(x + frameWidth),
            (int)(y + frameHeight));

    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, frames.get(currentFrame), destination, p);

}
```

Извините пожалуйста если что-то не так с вопросом, я только зарегистрировался.

Comment: Ну... Может за границы экрана вы вышли и там отрисовали?..

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Мне кажется нет, так как все спрайты передвигаются вверх по переменным и как мне кажется отрисовывается только определённый из них.